# How can I make this Xaml a Template?

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, refactoring

Without using code, how can I turn this into a Template?

I have about 10 of these, and my code is getting huge. It is working perfectly, I am just looking for ways to clean up the code, I am just not familiar enough with templating and resourcing animations and triggers to do this.

Thanks in advance.

```
    <RadioButton Width="35" Height="35" Content="RadioButton" Visibility="Visible" IsChecked="False" Margin="2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5" Template="{DynamicResource RadioTemplate}" >
        <RadioButton.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Source="..\Content\img.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                </BulletDecorator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </RadioButton.Resources>
        <RadioButton.BitmapEffect>
            <OuterGlowBitmapEffect x:Name="imageGlow" GlowColor="#FFeeba00" Opacity="1" GlowSize="0" />
        </RadioButton.BitmapEffect>
        <RadioButton.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="imageGlow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="GlowSize" From="0" To="10" Duration="0:0:.15" AutoReverse="False" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="imageGlow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="GlowSize" From="10" To="0" Duration="0:0:.15" AutoReverse="False" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </RadioButton.Triggers>
    </RadioButton>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a style.

```
<Style x:Key="RadioStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2.5"/>
    <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="#FFeeba00" Opacity="1" GlowSize="0" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                </BulletDecorator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
<!--Continued-->
```

And the rest (SO seems to cut off long code snippets):

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BitmapEffect.GlowSize" From="0" To="10" Duration="0:0:.15" AutoReverse="False" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BitmapEffect.GlowSize" From="10" To="0" Duration="0:0:.15" AutoReverse="False" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

For each button, you'll have something like this:

```
<RadioButton Style="{DynamicResource RadioStyle}" Visibility="Visible" IsChecked="False">
    <Image Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Source="..\Content\img.png" Stretch="Fill" />
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: You can add the remaining properties to the style as well, but I thought that some properties would vary for each button: Content, Visibility, IsChecked.

Comment: It's possible that you may need to vary other properties as well (Height, Width, Margin). Simply remove them from the style and add them to each button. You can also override the style value with a new local value if necessary.

Comment: You're not using the Content property at all, so I would use it for that. I edited my post.